# Getting different values in for loop when using (_) and (i)

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to coding and I am wondering if someone could explain to me why I get different values when using "for i in range ()" compared to "for _ in range ()". When I execute:

```
for i in range (64):
    i = i * 2
    print(i)
```

I get 2,4,6,8,10, etc. But when I run:

```py
i = 1
for _ in range (64):
    i = i * 2
    print(i)
```

I get 2,4,8,6,32,64,128, etc. I would expect these values but when I run this with the above code. What's the difference between using (i) and (_)?

Answer (score 0):

In the `for i in` version, `i` gets reset to the current step in the range during each iteration step. It's equivalent to:

```
i = 0
i = i * 2
print(i) # prints 0
i = 1
i = i * 2
print(i) # prints 2
i = 2
i = i * 2
print(i) # prints 4
...
```

When you using `for i in range(...)`, `i` doesn't keep any memory of its value from the previous iteration. The `range` object just returns the next value in the sequence, and this gets assigned to `i` each time.

But when you use `for _ in`, you're not assigning the `i` variable each time. This time it's like:

```
i = 1
_ = 0
i = i * 2
print(i) # prints 2
_ = 1
i = i * 2
print(i) # prints 4
_ = 2
i = i * 2
print(i) # print 8
...
```

This time, `i` keeps its value from the previous iteration, because the range element is being assigned to `_` rather than `i`.

There's nothing special about `_`, it's an ordinary variable name. But by convention we use this when we need to assign to a variable but aren't going to use it further.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between `for i in range(64)` and `for _ in range(64)` is the use of the loop variable.

In `for i in range(64)`, `i` takes on the values of the numbers in the range from **0 to 63**. This means that each time the loop is run, `i` is updated with the next number in the **range**.

In `for _ in range(64)`, the loop variable `_` is a **placeholder** that does not receive a value from the range. This is used when you want to run the loop a certain number of times, but you don't need to use the values generated by the range.

In simpler terms, `i` is used to keep track of the **values** in the **range**, while `_` is just used to run the loop a certain number of times *without* using the values generated by the range.